# how to determine exception to be expected, unknown or service exception in java

Tags: java, exception

what is a good way to decide which exception you categorize as expected, unknown or service exception in java.

I am right know writing a web service. I am trying to create 3 category for exception.
expected, unknown, and service.

What would be a good  standard to chose which exception you put it into expected, unknown and service?

Comment: Need more explanation, I guess!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think of Exceptions in Java in two categories: The ones you can do something about it, and the ones there's nothing you can do about.

For example:
If the JVM runs out of memory: there's nothing your app can do about it;
If there's no more space on the disk: nothing your app can do about it.

However, if the user entered an invalid argument (a number was expected but symbols were given instead), then the code can thrown an Exception (IllegalArgumentException) and you can elegantly show a message to the user, asking that a valid number be entered.

In this sense, IllegalArgumentException is expected and should be handled, whereas the memory exception is not expected and can't be handled.

So, as a guideline, expected exceptions are the ones that can be handled, and the program can recover from, and unknown are the ones that the program is not expecting and cannot recover from. That doesn't mean they should not be acknowledged. For example, you could have a logging system which logs all exceptions, and it would be good if you could log both checked and unchecked exceptions.

I am assuming you are calling "service" exceptions when you are using a service which is not part of your code, and on which you have no control. The exceptions on the service also follow the same standard, and will throw only the two exceptions as well.

For an in-depth explanation on Exceptions: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/